# Delete data from database using PHP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, window.location

I am working on a PHP file. I am trying to make a table that shows the list of products from database. There will be also a button for deleting any product. I have used javascript for deleting products from database. I have written the code and could not find anything wrong. When I click delete button, it shows me the confirmation box, but does not delete the product. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("grocery_shop",$con);

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
session_start();


    $sql = mysql_query("select * from products");


if($_GET['did']){
    mysql_query("delete from products where product_id='$_GET[did]'");
    header("Location: product.php");
}

?>
<table border="1px" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Serial No</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>       
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Delete Product</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $i=1;
    while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['product_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['product_type'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['price'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href=\"javascript:delproduct(id=$u[product_id])\">Delete</a>";?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>

    <script>
    function delproduct(id){
        var msg = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?");

    if (msg) {
        window.location = "product.php?did="+product_id;
    }
    }
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Are any errors being reported?

Comment: Nope...everything is okay. just can not delete the data.

Comment: Does it redirect to `product.php`?

Comment: Yes...The page redirects to product.php.

Comment: Off topic, but important: Please note that PHP's `mysql_query()` and related functions are obselete. They are deprecated in currently supported PHP versions, and will be removed entirely in new version due for release this month. You should strongly consider switching your code to use the more up-to-date `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries. See also [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Also, please note that by using a `$_GET` variable directly in your query like that, you are leaving your code wide open to SQL injection hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your javascript, the product_id doesn't exist

```
   if (msg) {
        window.location = "product.php?did="+id;
    }
```

For debugging purposes try to replace this with your code and let us know the error message you get.

```
if($_GET['did']){
    mysql_query("delete from products where product_id='".$_GET['did']."'");
    echo "delete from products where product_id='".$_GET['did']."'";
    echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() ;    
    die();
    //header("Location: product.php");
}
```

additionally also try to run the query without the single quotes, i am assuming product_id is an integer.

so `mysql_query("delete from products where product_id=".$_GET['did']);`

Comment: Thanks....I already solved th problem. but your solution is right. the problem was in my javascript. Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the '' around did in $_GET[did]:

```
mysql_query("delete from products where product_id='{$_GET['did']}'");
```

Also, as @chris85 noted, is not a good idea to use $_GET or $_POST directly, remember to sanitize these values before using it in a query.

```
$did = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'did', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
mysql_query("delete from products where product_id={$did}");
```

Comment: You should write what you have corrected. Also SQL injection note.

Comment: can you var_dump($_GET) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try: **delproduct($u[product_id])** instead of **delproduct(id=$u[product_id])**

```
mysql_query("delete from products where product_id='".$_GET['did']."'");

while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['product_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['product_type'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $u['price'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href=\"javascript:delproduct($u[product_id])\">Delete</a>";?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. After using it, it even does not show confirmation message.

Comment: Can you try again? I have edited the answer. Show on $_GET['did']

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("grocery_shop",$con);

 error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
session_start();


$sql = mysql_query("select * from products");


if($_GET['did']){
mysql_query("delete from products where product_id='$_GET[did]'");
header("Location: product.php");
}

?>
<table border="1px" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Serial No</th>
<th>Product Name</th>       
<th>Product Type</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Delete Product</th>
 </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=1;
while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['product_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['product_type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['quantity'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $u['price'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<a href=\"javascript:delproduct(".$u[product_id].")\">Delete</a>";?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php
     $i++;
     }
    ?>

<script>
function delproduct(id){
     var product_id = id;
    var msg = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?");

   if (msg) {
      window.location = "product.php?did="+product_id;
  }
  }
   </script>
</table>
```